# How to export body e-mail line by line in excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, email, outlook, export

I`m just begining to learn c# and i ask if you please help me with the code below to export in excel like described below :

I have a subfolder where emails contain a reply to an approval request email and i need to export this e-mails in excel this way ;

Aprroval response from the body of the response email in a cell and the date of the response in other cell

From the approval request : sender email in one cell , recipient in one cell , subject in one cell , date of approval request email in one cell and from the body of the email the first line of the email body in a cell , the second line in other cell...

For the begining i have the code below but i know is not right because the xlsx file is not populated.Please help me with the code below , and i ask if it is possible to write to excel line by line from the body of the email.If is possible i ask for a hint how to do it.

Thank you !

```
public static void getEmails()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder = null;

        string fileTest = "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\test.xlsx";
        if (File.Exists(fileTest))
        {
            File.Delete(fileTest);
        } 

        Excel.Application oApp;
        Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;

        oApp = new Excel.Application();
        oWB = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        try
        {
            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            ns.Logon("daniel.tou@btrl.ro", "XXXXX", false, true);
            inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            subFolder = inboxFolder.Folders["Octavian"]; //folder.Folders[1]; also works
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Name: {0}, EntryId: {1}", subFolder.Name, subFolder.EntryID);
            Console.WriteLine("Num Items: {0}", subFolder.Items.Count.ToString());

            for (int i = 1; i <= subFolder.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)subFolder.Items[i];

                oSheet.Cells[i, 1] = i.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[i, 2] = item.Subject;
                oSheet.Cells[i, 3] = item.SentOn.ToLongDateString();
                oSheet.Cells[i, 4] = item.Body.ToString();


            }

        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ns = null;
            app = null;
            inboxFolder = null;
            oWB.SaveAs(fileTest);
            oWB.Close();
            oApp.Quit();
        }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's ok now , the problem was with the file beeing created on c.

If You could guide me on how to write to excel the table from e email body in a sense that i want the first cell of the table to be write on a cell în excel the second cell of the table in other cell in excel an so on.

Thank's.